# How to check for cps using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game that requires a lot of clicking. Obviously, I would like to prevent cheating - and that includes AutoClicker. The way I thought of is to check for CPS and see if it exceeds a certain limit. How do I check for CPS?

Comment: Just like you'd think--attach a handler to keypresses and either check intra-character timing, or aggregate over a setTimeout and check on timeout expiry (and remember to clear the count and restart the timer).

Answer (score 3):

By CPS you mean "clicks per second"?

If so, you could initiate a counter-variable with a value of 0, then have an eventlistener count it up on each click.

Additionally add an interval which sets the countervalue back to zero after each second and maybe export the last counter-value into another variable "lastCPS" or so..

After 1 second, lastCPS should always hold the last-measured CPS.

Comment: *Or*, you could have an array of all the clicks per second since the start. You can then either average it (although I advise against it because gamers can click fast in "bursts", which averaging eradicates that factor), or do some calculations of your own to detect if the user is just a good clicker or can click fast in bursts, or if it is an autoclicker.